# Configure keep-alive for EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Django app running on a python instance with Nginx as the webserver.

I'm getting a 60 second timeout for one of my operations. According to the docs, you want to increase the load balancer's idle timeout above the default 60 seconds (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html)

It also says:

> we recommend that you enable the HTTP keep-alive option for your EC2 instances. You can enable HTTP keep-alive in the web server settings for your EC2 instances

Well I'm not sure how to do this or where that setting is. Can anyone point me to where the `keep-alive` option is?

Comment: The isn't an EC2 specific thing. In your case you would need to look for the keep-alive setting in your Nginx configuration.

Answer (score 5):

I'm running into the same issue now and have come to the conclusion that it's just a poorly worded bit of docco and as Mark B suggests in his comment, it's referring to setting the Keep-Alive header from your nginx/apache webserver config rather than on the ec2 instance itself.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem several times for months:
“504 Gateway Timeout: The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.”
Yeah, ideally maybe no request should take more than 60 seconds but sometimes we need it.
Here are what I did:

1. Increased “Environment > Configuration > Updates, monitoring, and logging > Platform software > Max execution time” like we do in local development environment, where it is sufficient! But guess what? It wasn’t sufficient for AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
2. So I started to search for extra information to catch what I missed and I encountered this:
   https://aws.amazon.com/tr/blogs/aws/elb-idle-timeout-control/
   So, a new term was added to my terminology: Idle Timeout (for Load Balancers).
   I found this months ago but tried and again… failed.
   I really couldn’t understand why after changing these two settings, my requests still get cut at 60 seconds. How annoying!
3. So, this time, I thought I could find better and more up-to date information on AWS Documentation and I found this:
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-idle-timeout.html
   And this time, a new term drew my attention: “HTTP keep-alive”. Good, but where to find it and how to set it? Not told. It is what I was searching and I came here under this question.

The previous answers gave me clues for finding the answer and here is **my solution**:

1. I found the Apache configuration file “/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf”
2. I increased Timeout and KeepAliveTimeout values:
   [image]
   This article may also be helpful: https://www.fastcomet.com/kb/enable-keep-alive-apache
3. I tried the request again but didn’t work. I went to Elastic Beanstalk environment and did “Actions > Restart app server(s)” (excitement, heart goes bump bump) and… **it worked!**
   It’s good to see the green :)
   [image]
4. Now I have a new question: is it still going to work if I make a new deployment or if there is a new instance? So, I try that: The values changed back! :(
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

```
sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
**keepalive_timeout   65;**
types_hash_max_size 2048;
```

Comment: Can you help the OP by indicating exactly which file you are setting this option?

Comment: I too am having trouble figuring out how to turn this on for apache.  I don't see anything with "alive" in the php.ini,  Does anyone know how to set this on apache?

Answer (score 1):

for apache2
cd /etc/apache2/
vi apache2.conf
find out keep alive option there